# How to assign the contents of one model to another in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller

I have the following create action:

```
def create
    @order = Order.new(params[:order])

    if params[:same_as_above] == "1"
      @order.billing_address.name = @order.shipping_address.name
      @order.billing_address.number = @order.shipping_address.number
      @order.billing_address.street = @order.shipping_address.town
    end

    if @order.save
      if @order.purchase
        render :action => "success"
      else
        render :action => "failure"
      end
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

It works, but seems a bit cumbersome and brittle in the way i copy the shipping address to the billing address, attribute by attribute. Is there a better way please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@order.billing_address.attributes = @order.shipping_address.attributes
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If your models are set up correctly, you can use:

```
@order.billing_address = @order.shipping_address
```

Comment: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in OrdersController#create
BillingAddress(#18825000) expected, got ShippingAddress(#18874550)

Comment: That's essentially what I meant by models not being set up correctly.... Why are there two sets of classes and tables for `Address` - why both `ShippingAddress` and `BillingAddress`?

Comment: Because one tables data will be kept, while the other will be cleared on a regular basis. Thats why i have the separation.